# PHP - Dropdown list with submit button

Tags: php, html, smarty

I've been trying to create a dropdown list with a submit button. The only thing I need to get back to the controller is the value `$ID` of the selected trip. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code. Here it is:

```
<form action="{$url.global}/tripsearch" method="post">
    <select name="formSearch" name="IDtrip">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        {foreach from=$trips item=v}
            <option value="{$v.ID}" name="IDtrip">{$v.ID}   {$v.title}</option>
        {/foreach}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

By the way, here is how I process the value in the controller:

```
$Idtrip = Filter::getString('IDtrip');
```

I always get a bool(false)

Comment: Note - `<option>` tags don't have name attributes - `<option value="{$v.ID}" name="IDtrip>` AND even if they did you are missing the closing quote `name="IDtrip` which could cause issues in your html code

Comment: I had the closing quote in `name="IDtrip"` in the code but I left it out the post. I edited this. Also I tried removing `name` quote from `<option>` but still having the same problem

Comment: `Filter` object is yours? What the method `getString()` makes? Please, show the entire code.

Comment: This is just the way PHP works. At least in PHP Storm. It gets the value of the variable you pass with POST method.

Comment: Your select tag has two name attributes one of which is also defined as attribute for option tag generated by foreach. You need name as an attribute just for the select tag and access it by that name in php script.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I just found out, fixed it and posted it as response. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had two name attributes in `<select>` quote. I took out the name attribute from the `<option>` tag too because it was useless. This works just fine:

```
<form action="{$url.global}/tripsearch" method="post">
<select name="IDtrip">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    {foreach from=$trips item=v}
        <option value="{$v.ID}">{$v.ID}   {$v.title}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```